# Do Voronoi cells "converge" towards their centroid?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, voronoi-diagram

If you do the following:

1. Place random points on a finite surface
2. Draw the Voronoi diagram using the points as germs
3. Calculate the centroid of each cell
4. Repeat step 2 and 3 indefinitely using the centroids obtained in step 3 as germs.

How does that look like? Does it converge to a diagram where all the germs are in the centroid of their cell? I suspect there's a convergence most of the times, but is there a set of starting points where it *doesn't* converge?

Secondary question: Does the fact that the surface is finite change anything? I suspect it does, considering borders affects the position of the centroid around the edge (so after a few iterations, it affects all cells) but not the Voronoi cell.

Comment: Centroids cannot be considered for infinite surfaces. Some of the cells will be unbounded and thus their centroids pushed to $\infty$. I find the question very interesting though.

Comment: @nicomezi You're right, I didn't specify it but if you use an infinite surface, you'd also need an infinite number of starting points, so all cells are bounded.

Comment: You've reinvented [Lloyd's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lloyd%27s_algorithm)!

Comment: It seems that [this paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00922957/document) answers your question.

Comment: The big problem with Lloyd's algorithm is that convergence is severely "polluted" by the border cells. Ideally one should periodize the distributions of initial points i.e. consider a toric "world"...

Comment: This question was brought to my attention via the [Pearl Dive project](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/53556122#53556122).

Comment: @nicomezi I would really appreciate it if you could expand a little on your comments and post an answer to this question.

Comment: Will do. It is just that I do not have that much to add ! @XanderHenderson

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This [paper](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-00922957/document) answers the question (and goes far beyond).

Reformulating theorem 2.1 tells you that, for every finite set of random points over a bounded surface, the iterated centroids will converges to some distribution. Although, as the paper mentions, the distribution limit may not be optimal in the sense that they do not necessarily split the surface evenly (see quantization error in the paper).

Unboundedness implies a lot of theoretical complications, which is in fact the main point of interest of this paper. Convergence can still be ensured by adding constraints to your initial set of points.